# c# dimetric projection of cube

Tags: c#, winforms, 3d

I want to draw a dimetric projection of a cube

[image]

the matrix by which I will multiply:

[image]

```
        float p = 33f;
        float f =41f;
        float[,] rotation = { { (float)Math.Cos(f*Math.PI/180), (float)Math.Sin(p*Math.PI/180)*(float)Math.Cos(f*Math.PI/180), 0, 0 },
                       { 0, (float)Math.Cos(p*Math.PI/180), 0, 0 },
                       { (float)Math.Sin(f*Math.PI/180),((-(float)Math.Sin(p*Math.PI/180))* (float)Math.Cos(f*Math.PI/180)), 0, 0 },
                       {0, 0, 0, 1 } };
```

but I haven't found information anywhere, which angles should I choose. I tried with 33° and 41°
but it's not exactly like dimetry..

[image]

everything is clear with isometry. There I have to choose angles 35° and 45°.

[image]

But I didn't find any relation for dimetry. Please tell me which angles should I choose in dimetry?

Comment: IIRC, ISO defines the base angles as 7° and 42°, with a sight direction of ~20°. Then you have to choose the scale of Z. In computer graphics, side view, you may have a different representation, e.g. `x = x1 − 2(y1 − y); z = 4(y1 − y)`

Comment: @Jimi When rotated by an angle ψ relative to the Y axis, by an angle φ around the X axis and then projected onto the Z = 0 ..then we get the matrix that I threw off at the very beginning . isn't it enough just to pick the right angles ψ and φ?

Comment: Isn't Z meant to be = 1, using the *standard* angles?

Comment: @Jimi probably..I took this from the study guide, I'm not sure that everything is correct there..